# Determining the graph a parametric function.

Tags: vectors, graphing-functions, self-learning, curves, parametric

I know that the graph of $\overline{r}(t) = \langle \cos(t), t, \sin(t)\rangle$ is a cylinder aligned along the $y$-axis, however how can I determine from $\overline{r}(t) = \langle \cos(t), -\cos(t), \sin(t)\rangle$ that is is only a circle? What about changing the $y$-coordinate from $t$ to $-\cos(t)$ causes this change in shape?

Comment: The first figure is a helix, not a cylinder. For the second, you can see that none of the coordinates exceeds $[-1,1]$ interval. The second figure is in fact an ellipse.